# Build não aparece para submit, mas aparece em atividade

Tags: ios, build, appstore

Fiz um upload de uma atualização do app, porém a build aparece no menu `atividade` mas não aparece para `submit for review`. É normal não aparecer de imediato?

Comment: Você diz naquele botão +, onde selecionamos a versão da build?

Comment: Exatamente, não aparece esse botão.

Comment: Isso é normal, espera alguns minutos e atualize a página. Leva algum tempo para sincronizar o xcode com a nuvem. (o tempo varia com o tamanho do arquivo). Vai atualizando que jaja aparece, se não aparecer força subir novamente o arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado, mas já tem umas duas horas que enviei a atualização e até agora nada, mas vou esperar até amanhã para ver.

Comment: Loguei hoje na app store connect e ainda nada, vou subir uma build nova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá Amigo Boa tarde esse comportamento é comum imagino que na área de atividade você pode perceber que o app ta com um tom meio cinza apos uns minutos normalmente 30 min(existem casos que demoram horas) o botão para submeter aparecerá

Comment: Obrigado, mas já tem umas duas horas que enviei a atualização e até agora nada, mas vou esperar até amanhã para ver.

Comment: cara tenta mandar outra vez pode ser que deu algum problema no envio

Comment: Fiz um teste pelo testFlight e todou liso, só estou esperando o Submit for review mesmo

Comment: Está subindo um novo app? ou atualização?

Comment: subindo atualização

Comment: Loguei hoje na app store connect e ainda nada, vou subir uma build nova.

Answer (score 2):

Galera, já identifiquei o problema, eu precisa clicar em `+ versão ou plataforma`. Desde já muito obrigado a todos.

Att;

Comment: Bruno, não utilize o campo de respostas para comentários! Quando seu problema for resolvido, basta marcar a resposta como aceita, caso contrário adicione mais informações na sua pergunta para que a comunidade possa entender melhor e te ajudar. Bem vindo ao sopt o/

Comment: oi bruno, por favor onde esta este botao??  "+ versão ou plataforma" estou com o mesmo problema...

Answer (score 1):

Fiz o upload de uma nova build, aparece assim:
[image: print do menu atividades]

[image: print da compilação]